# Inverse Laplace transform of the feedback system transfer function with delay

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory, inverse-laplace, delay-differential-equations

I need to find a solution to the problem in the general case.
For given transfer function

$$
 W(s)=\frac{{{K}_{1}}{{e}^{-s{{T}_{1}}}}}{1+{{K}_{2}}{{e}^{-s{{T}_{2}}}}} 
$$

get the analytical formulas for the following inverse Laplace transform

$$ 
 h(t)={{\mathcal{L}}^{-1}}\left\{ \frac{W(s)}{s} \right\}
$$

Can I find a combination of hyperbolic functions expressions to apply? Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQAho.png) applicable ([source](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/auxiliary/inttrans/LapInv6.pdf))?

Comment: With Maple, if $t1>0$ then:$$\frac{\theta \! \left(t -\mathit{t1} \right) \mathit{k1} \left(\left(-\frac{1}{\mathit{k2}}\right)^{-{\lfloor \frac{t -\mathit{t1}}{\mathit{t2}}\rfloor}} \mathit{k2} +1\right)}{\mathit{k2} +1}$$ as text: `Heaviside(t-t1)*k1*((-1/k2)^(-floor((t-t1)/t2))*k2+1)/(k2+1)`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk, thank you! It will be interesting to check and compare with next answers

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $|K_2e^{-sT_2}|\lt 1$  we can proceed as follows.

$$
W(s)=K_1e^{-sT_1}\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^iK_2^ie^{-i T_2s}
$$

then

$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[\frac{W(s)}{s}\right] = K_1\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i K_2^i \theta (t-T_1-i T_2)
$$

where $\theta(\cdot)$ is the Heaviside Theta function.

Comment: thank you! I intend to use your and others answers and compare results.

Answer (score 0):

The inverse Laplace transform of $W(s)/s$ is the impulse response of the same system, which is the step response of the system $W(s)$. In term of signals, we have that $Y(s)=W(s)U(s)$. Going to the time-domain, we obtain the expression

$$y(t)=K_1u(t-T_1)-K_2y(t-T_2).$$

The delay $T_1$ is just going to shift the whole response by $T_1$ seconds. So, we may assume for now that $T_1=0$ for simplicity. Applying a step and assuming zero initial conditions yields for $t\in[0,T_2)$:

$$y(t)=K_1.$$

Propagating forward, we get for $t\in[T_2,2T_2)$

$$y(t)=K_1-K_2K_1=K_1(1-K_2).$$

Repeating this process over and over, we can observe that the impulse response is piecewise constant and that the values are related to the sequence

$$y_{n+1} = K_1-K_2y_n,\ y_0=K_1$$

It is a linear recurrence equation which is bounded and converging if and only if $|K_2|<1$, bounded but oscillatory if and only if $K_2=1$, and unbounded otherwise.

The general solution is given by
$$y_n = (-K_2)^nK_1+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-K_2)^{n-k-1}K_1,\ n\ge0$$

and we have that $y(t)=y_i$ for all $t\in[iT_2,(i+1)T_2)$.

Adding now the offset $T_1$, we get that the impulse response $h$ of $W(s)/s$  is given by
$$h(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{rl}
0&,t\in[0,T_1)\\
y(t-T_1)&,t\ge T_1
\end{array}\right.$$

Interestingly, we can connect this result with the answer from Cesareo by noting that $$y_{n+1}-
\sum_{i=0}^ny_i=(-1)^{n+1}K_1K_2^{n+1},$$ and we recover the expression

$$h(t)=K_1\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^iK_2^i\theta(t-T_1-iT_2),\ t<T_1+(n+1)T_2.$$

In the case where $|K_2|<1$, the limit as $n\to\infty$ exists and we have

$$h(t)=K_1\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-1)^iK_2^i\theta(t-T_1-iT_2),\ t\ge0.$$

Comment: thank you! I intend to use your and others answers and compare results.